# How to provide OpenAPI 'tag' group descriptions for a .NET Core 7 minimal API?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, openapi, minimal-apis

I've grouped my API endpoints into two tag/groups: "MCP Provider" and "Nexgen Provider". How can I apply a description to the tags themselves?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have already installed the package: ***Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations***, then adding the following codes in your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>   
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now adding the codes in ***program.cs***:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>{
var xmlFile = ${Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
c.EnableAnnotations();});
```

Last, adding the description which you want to use in front of the controller via the codes:

```
[SwaggerTag("This is a test")]
```

Here is my test result:
[image]

You can get more infromation from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments).

Comment: How do you add the `SwaggerTag` attribute to minimal APIs?

Comment: @silkfire check out this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76876810/2501279)