# .NET 7/8 How do I provide a description/summary on a Group with Minimap APIs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, openapi, minimal-apis

I am adding a group of minimal APIs like this:

```cs
var myapi = app.MapGroup("myapi").WithTags("My API").WithOpenApi();

// and then
myapi .MapGet($"/", GetAllStuff).WithName("GetAllStuff");
myapi .MapGet($"/{id}", GetSomeStuff).WithName("GetSomeStuff");
```

This gives me the Swagger UI, but I am currently not able to have a description for both the APIs, in other words, a summary of the Group. Any ideas?

Comment: The same question is asked here, but the answer doesn't pertain to minimal APIs, but controller-based APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75429292/how-to-provide-openapi-tag-group-descriptions-for-a-net-core-7-minimal-api

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a build-in way (like `WithDescription` for endpoints) to provide this data but you can workaround with [document filters](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#document-filters):

```
public class TagDescriptionsDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Tags = new List<OpenApiTag>
        {
            new OpenApiTag { Name = "My API", Description = "My API does something" }
        };
    }
}
```

And

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opts => opts.DocumentFilter<TagDescriptionsDocumentFilter>());
```

Obviously tag names must match.

[image]